# asp.net gridview fill into html table column

Tags: html, asp.net

I write this html code into my webform.aspx:

```
<td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" style="direction: rtl" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
```

How can i show in my table column fit height and width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post here since I cannot comment yet.

I am sorry but your question isn't much clear, so I'll give my shot.

If you're talking about row height, your best options would be to give a cssclass to your RowStyle and AlternatingRowStyle. Now thats only for rows, if you want to give a style to your columns, you need to work with TemplateField. Usually just adjusting the header column width helps, but you can add our cssclass to each item inside the template field. Ex:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item1" SortExpression="Item1" ItemStyle-CssClass="Col1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Something
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

---

OR

---

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item1" SortExpression="Item1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Something
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="Col1" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and then on your stylesheet name something like this:

```
.Col1 {
    width: 100px;
}
```